# How to use spring-boot integrated liquibase

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I would like to use spring-boot integrated liquibase, maven project application configuration file and pom.xml should be how to configure? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can find integration examples at this [`GitHub Project`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-liquibase/src/main/resources/application.properties)

Answer (score 0):

just add liquibase dependancy in your pom.xml - the schema update will be launched automatically at startup of your application.

By default your master changelog is located in db/changelog/db.changelog-master.[json|xml|yml] as resource